# Почему компилятор не видит тип перечисления?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Делаю первое устройство на ардуино, и во время программирования возникла ошибка, якобы компилятор не видит что `MathOperator` это тип, хотя строчки выше, он это видит. У меня есть перечисление `MathOperator` и класс `Calculator`. У него есть приватное поле `MathOperator _operator`. Здесь всё нормально работает. Но если я добавлю публичный метод `MathOperator getOperator()`, то выводится ошибка:

> error: 'MathOperator' does not name a type; did you mean 'operator+'?

Ломал голову, но всё таки не выяснил, что к чему. Надеюсь вы поможете. Фрагмент кода:

```cpp
enum MathOperator 
{
  None, Add, Multiply, Divide
};

class Calculator
{
  private:
    int64_t _firstOperand = 0;
    int64_t _secondOperand = 0;
    MathOperator _operator;  
  
  public: 
    // -- Methods for working with operands --
    int64_t getFirstOperand()
    {
      return this->_firstOperand;
    }
    
    int64_t getSecondOperand()
    {
      return this->_secondOperand;
    }
  
    void updateFirstOperand(int (*func)(int))
    {
      this->_firstOperand = func(_firstOperand);
    }
    // ---------------------------------------
  
    // -- Methods for working with operator --
    MathOperator getOperator()
    {
      return this->_operator;
    }
    // ---------------------------------------
    
    String valueToString(int64_t number)
    {
      String str;
      
      while (number > 0) 
      {
        str = String((int32_t)(number % 10)) + str;
        number /= 10;
      }
      
      return str;
    }
  
    void clear()
    {
      this->_firstOperand = 0;
      this->_secondOperand = 0;
      this->_operator = MathOperator::None;
    }
};
```

Если публичный метод `getOperator()` закомментировать, то код скомпилируется.

Comment: [Всё компилируется.](https://onlinegdb.com/WqtQshIMG)

Comment: @maestro ух-хух-хух... у меня на этом сайте тоже компилируется. Но почему в программе нет... видимо проблема уже в программе, не в коде. Попробуем разобраться.

Comment: Хрустальный шар подсказывает, что у вас циклические зависимости в заголовках.

Comment: @user7860670 мне кажется, но хрустальный шар ошибается.. никаких циклических зависимостей нет..

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, привести полное сообщение об ошибке? Есть ли что-то у тебя перед `getOperator()` или это весь класс?

Comment: @Kane, это весь мой класс. Я использую `Tinkercad`, для создания схемы и её программирования. Но мне кажется, проблема именно в ней. И да, это вся ошибка, что мне дал `Tinkercad`

Answer (score -1):

На языке С++ должно быть так:

```
 typedef enum {
     None, Add, Multiply, Divide
 } MathOperator;
```

Comment: Это как раз на си использовалось, а не на си++.

Comment: На си++ нельзя тайпдеф?

Comment: Можно, но зачем, когда там автоматически выводится тип без префиксов `enum`, `struct`

Comment: Можно `typedef` не значит нужно `typedef`. В современном C++ `typedef` не употребляется, т.к. есть лучшие альтернативы.

Comment: @Kane Вопрос про AVR_GCC.

Comment: Что это меняет?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, если бы дело было в typedef, у него бы всё не компилировалось, а ему хватает закомментировать один метод и другие использования компилируются.

Comment: @Qwertiy Возможно без этого метода оптимизатор просто удаляет это приватное поле.

Comment: Оптимизатор не может удалить приватное поле. Там ошибка в коде, который не показан в приведённом фрагменте.